# Error calculating the area between two lines using "integrate"

Tags: r, area, curve, numerical-integration, integral

I'm attempting to calculate the area between two plots using R's `integrate` function.    I have two forecast curves that I'm able to place on the same plot and also shade in the area between the two curves, for visualisation:

```
x1 = seq(1,200,1)
y1 = # 200 numbers from 0.02 - 1.000
y2 = # 200 numbers from 0.00 - 0.95

plot(x1,y1,type="l",bty="L",xlab="Forecast Days",ylab="Curve Actuals")
points(x1,y2,type="l",col="red")

polygon(c(x1,rev(x1)),c(y2,rev(y1)),col="skyblue")
```

Following the example here https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2010-September/251756.html I've attempted to execute the same code for my data to calculate the are between the two curves.  As stated in the example *"the area between two curves is the same as the integral of the difference between these two curves (resp. its absolute values)"*:

```
f1 = approxfun(x1, y1-y2)     # piecewise linear function
f2 = function(x) abs(f1(x))   # take the positive value

integrate(f2, 1, 200)
```

However I get the following error:

```
Error in integrate(f2, 1, 200) : maximum number of subdivisions reached
```

Appreciate any clarity that can be shed on this.  Thanks!

Comment: You can increase the number of `subdivisions`, but then you are likely to get a roundoff error. Instead I'd suggest to calculate the integral without approximations. It's not that difficult using some geometry.

Answer (score 1):

Increasing the number of subdivisions, as suggested in an earlier comment by @Roland, executes correctly.  It does produce an absolute error, but very minute.

```
f1 = approxfun(x1, y1-y2)     # piecewise linear function
f2 = function(x) abs(f1(x))   # take the positive value

area1 = integrate(f2, 1, 200, subdivisions = 300)
> area1
9.327692 with absolute error < 8.1e-05
```

Answer (score 0):

Is `approxfun()` returning a function? You need to have the difference of `f1` and `f2` saved as a function, not a set a point differences. For example

```
f1 <- function(x) { 2 * x - 1}
f2 <- function(x) { x^2 - 3 * x}
abs_dif <- function(x) { abs( f1(x) - f2(x) ) } 
integrate(abs_dif, -1, 1)
```

Try expressing the `f1` and `f2` as functions then try the second two lines of code.

Comment: Thanks for responding. In the example I included from the R Help forum and where I got the original code, it was executed exactly as I have written mine and the data itself is not too dissimilar to my own (the seq used on the x axis is smaller, the y-values similar to my own).  When running the example used there, I get the exact same answer, so I'm not sure why I would need to make the changes to mine that you suggest.